# Is there any research on what elements are choosen on lists of X elements?

Tags: neuromarketing

Let's say there is a list with 5 elements listed, with similar characteristics (I am taking as an example a marketing mail with product recommendations). Is there any way to know if there is a preference on clicking on the first element, rather than the second, etc? Could it be also based on the number of elements listed that the preferences change?

Comment: Could you [edit] to tell us what research you've already done on the subject, what this has shown and where you got stuck? We're expected to do prior "homework" here before asking.

Comment: I noticed this with an ad campaign at my workplace. The third element listed in a 5 element list was the one getting fewer clicks by far (and all emails had different elements listed, so a lack of interest on the third element "just because", couldn't be the reason), and I wondered whether there was a psychological explanation for this. I don't know how to word out the question, but what I was asking for, is if this "thing" has a name, is it a known effect, has a wikipedia page, etc.